# What bird species is this? (Heron-like waterfowl from China)

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I need help identifying this bird.  (Some sort of heron?)

It was seen in Wuhan, Hubei, China, in September.

It is very common there.  It can also swim like a duck, but I've only seen it do this once (it's not something they commonly do).  I can supply more photos upon request.

These are two different individuals:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd also be grateful for tips on websites I could use to look up these birds.  Most of what I can find is for North-America only, and I'm having a hard time finding Chinese birds.

Comment: My two guesses were Striated heron or Night heron, as the juveniles of both look similar to this.  But I haven't seen any birds that would look like the adults of either species.

Comment: juvenile night heron (Nycticorax nycticorax) INDEED good pics, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some external advice, I believe it might be a juvenile night heron (*Nycticorax nycticorax*), the only remaining question being why I didn't see any adults.

[Link to Google Image search results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=Nycticorax+nycticorax+juvenile)

**Update:** I went back to the same location today and saw some adult night herons, which convinced me that these were juveniles of the same species.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with juvenile striated heron. I ruled out others such as the [chinese pond heron](http://www.pbase.com/tombac/image/134271698) because of the spotted wing plumage and slightly different shape of the patch around the eye. The [night heron](http://www.google.se/imgres?imgurl=&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.birdinginformation.com%2Fbirds%2Fherons-bitterns-egrets%2Fblack-crowned-night-heron%2F&h=0&w=0&tbnid=5G3V-IauqM4e9M&zoom=1&tbnh=188&tbnw=268&docid=z9MbczxKVoi_YM&tbm=isch&ei=nGAqVNKJL6uiygObtILYCQ&ved=0CAQQsCUoAA) seems to have a more red eye than the [striated heron](http://www.gobirding.eu/Photos/StriatedHeron.php) and appears to have a stubbier beak.

[Arkive](http://www.arkive.org/striated-heron/butorides-striata/) is a good place to see a lot of pictures of birds, [this is a good birding site](http://carolinabirds.org/INDEX/WLD_indx_A.htm), and otherwise I use generic google searching (e.g. start with "herons china" or "herons asia") - this at least helps narrow down the search quite substantially and is considerably cheaper than having a library of the worlds bird books!

Comment: It does look very similar to the juvenile of the striated heron (so +1), but how would you explain that *all* the birds I saw were like this?  (I have tens of photos of several individuals so I don't have to rely on my memory.) Could they *all* be juveniles, with no adults around?